# How to store characters in a LInked list

Tags: c

I'm facing a problem with storing characters in the following code.
It is compiled but it is not taking 2nd,4th,6th... characters as inputs.

```
struct ll {
    char data;
    struct ll *next;
};
```

Here is the code for creating a Linked list.

```
struct ll* create_ll(struct ll *start){
    struct ll *p1,*p2;
    char a;
    printf("Enter q to stop\n");
    printf("Enter data:");
    scanf("%c",&a);
    while(a != 'q'){
    p1 = (struct ll*)malloc(sizeof(struct ll*));
    p1 -> data = a;
    if(start == NULL){
        start = p1;
        p2 = p1;
        p1 -> next = NULL;
        }
    else{
        p2 -> next = p1;
        p1 -> next = NULL;
        p2 = p1;
        }
    printf("Enter data:");
    scanf("%c",&a);;
    }
    return start;       
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code better.

Comment: Also warning: [Do not cast the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/1151654)

Comment: BTW you are malloc'ing the size of a pointer rather than the actual struct size. Should be `malloc(sizeof(struct ll));`

Comment: Should be `malloc(sizeof(*p1))` and be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
scanf("%c",&a);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c",&a);
    // ^ Space here
```

Your scanf is reading your <kbd>enter</kbd> key as `\n` character

You could have seen it as I suspect the program outputs `Enter data:` twice each time.